# SQL - Update table1 values from table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the value of column2 in table1 by getting the values from table 2 column2 with comparing both values of column1 on both tables. I am getting an error ("The multi-part identifier "dbo.PID0147_PEX_LCC.PEX_LCC" could not be bound.") with the query that I made below.

```
update 
BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM
Set 
PEX_LCC = dbo.PID0147_PEX_LCC.PEX_LCC
from
dbo.PID0147_DM d, dbo.PID0147_PEX_LCC p
where
d.CtryGrName = p.EWS_Country;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just Alias name makes a difference

```
Begin Tran
    update 
    d
    Set 
    PEX_LCC = p.PEX_LCC
    from
    dbo.PID0147_DM d inner join  dbo.PID0147_PEX_LCC p
    on
    d.CtryGrName = p.EWS_Country
    Rollback
```

;